# Best practice to keep the domain/url for loadbalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-fargate

I am using cdk to deploy fargate and loadbalancer system.

Every time I deploy by `cdk` the url and global IP is made such as

```
cdk-ecs-bb-aa-dx-XXXXXX.ap-northeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com
18.714.**.**
```

However this ip is changed every time `cdk destroy` and `cdk deploy`.

Is there any way to keep the same IP?

Or do I need to add some service to keep the IP (like Route 53?)

(If so, how can I keep the same address to regist in DNS)

What is the best practice when using fargate and loadbalancer.

I am not familiar the aws DNS or IP system yet.

Any help is appreciated, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, the approach is to use a CNAME record or Route53 Alias record pointing to the FQDN that is created when you instantiate the load balancer. Application load balancers can't be assigned EIP's, and they will randomly select available IP's from the CIDR ranges in the subnets where they are created. Hence, the best approach, if you have the option, is to utilize the name only when referring to the ALB, and using a friendly CNAME or Route 53 alias to refer to the generated FQDN.

If you have a hard requirement to use static IP's, this can be achieved by front-ending your ALB with either an NLB or Global Accelerator, which would maintain a static IP on the front end, and forward to your dynamically addressed ALB on the back end.

Comment: Thank you , let me ask one question. I understand that IP can not be fixed.  But,DNS  'cdk-ecs-bb-aa-dx-XXXXXX.ap-northeast-1.elb.amazonaws.com' can not be fixed either or can I fix it ? If not, how can I set the CNAME record? use ARN?

Comment: At the time of creation, when you receive the new FQDN for the given ALB that you have created, you can at that time update the corresponding CNAME either in Route53 or whichever DNS service you are using. The DNS FQDN will be created based on the format you noted in the question, and the unique ID (the XXXXX portion) will always be different and randomly generated, similar to an EC2 instance ID. The FQDN is durable for the lifetime of the ALB/NLB, but upon creation or deletion it will be recreated. Note that you do not need to change the ALB/NLB often, but could use it across builds.

Comment: Thank you very much, so my best practice is using `ALB DNS FQDN`, and set it as `CNAME` in `my DNS`. Then every time I destroy-> deploy, I put `FQDN` in `my DNS` manually. However not `destory`, just `deploy` `ALB DNS` doesn't change.

Comment: Yes that is all correct, good luck!